# epoll and send lag

Tags: c, linux, sockets, epoll

I'm using Linux 64 bit `Linux scv 3.2.0-39-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 28 00:28:53 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and have two processes using sockets which run on the same physical host.

One process (*A*) sends on a TCP/IP socket (would be a local socket given the host is the same) the following pieces of data:

1. 276 bytes
2. 16 bytes

This is done in 0.000023 seconds form process *A*. The data is being sent calling 2 times the `send` socket API.

Another process (*B*), receives the data via *epoll* using `epoll_wait(efd, events, 10, 5)`. Data is received as follows (time is taken with `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &cur_ts);`, what matters is relative difference):

1. Read data from socket buffer at 8051.177743 (276)
2. Call to epoll 8051.177763 again
3. Read data from socket buffer 8051.216250 (16)

Making the receiving process *lag* of 0.038507 seconds. Basically if the sending process *A* takes less than a *ms*, on the receiving side *epoll* to receive the data adds an additional lag of approximately 0.038 s.

Is this expected? What am I doing wrong?
Or how can I improve the situation?

Thanks

Comment: Point 3 is when second call to _epoll_ returns.

Comment: 40ms is standard time slice, looks like standard context switching on a single core.

Comment: Should I move away from _epoll_ if I want to reduce this lag? What do you suggest?

Comment: I am currently seeing something equivalent - however, I'm getting a lag of 0.2 seconds before epoll_wait returns instead of 38 ms :(. I don't believe that this is "native" to epoll "because it only works with a large number of fds". Something is wrong and it must be possible to actually explain what that is.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this expected? ...

Yes. I would expect that. Here's why:

> What am I doing wrong? ...

epoll was designed to be used in situations where large numbers of file descriptors need to be watched. That's what it's suitable for, and it seems to me that the situation you're using it for *isn't* that situation.

> ... how can I improve the situation?

If you want to improve the performance, *use the right tool for the job*. Don't use epoll for a single socket. Just use plain-old vanilla recv. If you're handling two or three sockets, consider using poll or select. If you're venturing into hundreds, then you might want to consider using epoll or kqueue.

Comment: Really? 0.038 s just to make the function call? Wasn't _epoll_ supposed to be O(1)? Anyway, the application should be able to manage 500+ connections, so I believe other techniques like 1 thread per connection seems impractical.

Comment: @Emanuele I would suggest that epoll takes roughly 0.038s whether you give it a small number of sockets or a large number of sockets. If it doesn't, then show me an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and I'll tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Emanuele I think that's a silly idea. Context switching would probably end up being even more expensive! A typical computer has what, four cores? Any more than one or two threads per core would be overkill. If you don't like epoll, consider a non-blocking poll or select loop running on all four cores, each handling a few hundred clients each. Try to design your solution to minimise thread locking such as mutexes and blocking IO operations, so you can focus on getting more processing done per thread rather than creating more threads to do more processing.

Comment: Even if the target system might have 24+ cores? As I said, target is not my mobile phone but a dedicated server. Anyway, current _epoll_ is acting on nonblocking sockets; AFAIK _epoll_ is better than _poll_ and _select_ performance wise. Why would be _poll_ better than _epoll_ (or _select_)? Any good article to point out there?

Comment: @Emanuele: The first sentence of [the epoll manual](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) seems to be informative: *epoll ... scales well to large numbers of watched fds.* Forget this word "*better*"; Meaningless. Either accept that epoll is slow for small numbers of sockets but scales well for large numbers of sockets, or use poll or select. select only monitors up to `FD_SETSIZE` sockets at a time, and that's typically a small number. Regardless of choice, you'll need to make sure you're using [non-blocking sockets](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#blocking).

Comment: Write a poll-based loop, a select-based loop and an epoll-based loop. Test them all with 20-30 clients on one thread. See which one takes the least amount of time to check for socket events for those 20-30 clients. Scale the most performant across each of your cores.